# Change user passwd with UID

Tags: users, passwd, multiuser

Is it possible to change a user's password by UID?

```
[root@CentOS7 ~]# id usera 
uid=1000(usera) gid=1000(usera) groups=1000(usera),10(wheel)
[root@CentOS7 ~]# man passwd
[root@CentOS7 ~]# passwd 1000
passwd: Unknown user name '1000'.
```

I don't see anything regarding UID in the `man passwd` [pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html)

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -e usera
usera:x:1000:1000::/home/usera:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Does `getent passwd 1000 | cut -d: -f1` get you on the way? Note that `getent passwd 651651`,  (some unknown UID), would give blank, which in turn would prompt change for current user. You might take advantage of exit status.

Comment: @user367890 I'm aware of the user name to change, I'm asking whether it is possible to change a user password solely by UID?

Comment: `passwd $(getent passwd username | cut -d: -f1)` ... I miss-typed and meant nick instead of 1000 ....

Answer (score 1):

You could get the username from the UID, passing that to `passwd`.

```
passwd $(id -nu $UID)
```